# What can I substitute for pineapple juice in this recipe?

Tags: substitutions, beverages, pineapple

My group in cooking class has to make a beverage and they chose my recipe coconut kiss. But, one of the members tells us she is allergic to pineapple. It is hard you see because I made it before and the pineapple really boosts the taste in the coconut cream. I want it to taste no less than it should and so I need a really good alternative for the pineapple juice.

What can I substitute? These are all the ingredients:

2c coconut cream,
2c pineapple juice,
1c apple cherry juice,
1c orange juice and
Crushed ice

Comment: Make sure that's their only food restriction -- often we can come up with a 'similar' thing, but it's *too* similar, so it's still a problem.  Food subs says orange or grapefruit.  If you can find it, blood orange juice has the sweetness of pineapple juice, but it might be *too* sweet in this case and not have enough sour to it.

Comment: Is she reacting to fresh pineapples or canned ones too? Protein digesting proteolytic enzymes in some fresh fruits causing inflammation is quite common. They can be denatured and deactivated by heat (65C should do it). Canned juice will not have active enzymes. That is assuming that it is not actual allergy.

Comment: Thanks but figured it out would just make it 1 c pineapple and 2 c orange she says it is only for fresh pineapple she has an allergy so since we are using boxed pineapple juice and I lessen it to 1 she should be fine

Comment: There are several other fruits known for proteolytic enzymes, kiwis and papayas come to mind immediately, great for tenderising meat or making pureed meat. I wonder if reaction to proteolytic enzymes is a real allergy involving an immune response or it is sensitivity. Does anyone know the answer to that? Boxed juice may not have had enough heat to deactivate these enzymes. So, do watch out.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute with mango or papaya juice.

It will not taste the same, but it will still have the exotic flavor.